# Given only a table name, get database data and edit it in a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a database table, but the schema changes too regularly to hard code the columns into the app (WPF app). How can I display all the rows from the table into a DataGrid and have it so the rows in the grid are editable?

Getting data from the database and updating the database I can do, but I'm having trouble trying to think of a way I can bind the contents of the DataGrid to some collection considering I can't program (for example) a model with the various columns as properties ahead of time - as the columns change quite frequently.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with a couple of converters which create a GridView for a ListView. I read the column names and the column data (formatted into strings) into arrays, and used these converters:

```
<ValueConversion(GetType(String()), GetType(GridView))>
Public Class TableToGridViewConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

Private Shared ReadOnly ItemConverter As New ArrayToItemConverter
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim header() As String = TryCast(value, String())
    Dim result As New GridView
    If header IsNot Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To header.Length - 1
            result.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn() With {.Header = header(i), .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding() With {.Converter = ItemConverter, .ConverterParameter = i}})
        Next
    End If
    Return result
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotSupportedException
End Function
End Class

<ValueConversion(GetType(String()), GetType(String))>
Public Class ArrayToItemConverter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    If TypeOf value Is String() AndAlso IsNumeric(parameter) Then
        Dim values() As String = value
        Dim index As Integer = CInt(parameter)
        If index >= 0 And index < values.Length Then
            result = values(index)
        End If
    End If
    Return result
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotSupportedException
End Function
End Class
```

The trick is to create a GridViewColumn for each column in your array, and use a converter which binds to an array of values and selects the value for the respective column using the column index as ConverterParameter. You would use it like this:

```
                    <ListView x:Name="TableDataListView" View="{Binding Path=DisplayTable.Header, Converter={StaticResource tableToGridView}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayRows}">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>        
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
```

where the bound properties DisplayTable.Header and DisplayRows would contain the string array with the column names, and an array of string arrays containing the actual data, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a different and much simpler approach, if it fits your requirements: Just use a System.Data.DataTable to hold your data and set AutoGenerateColumns="True" on the DataGrid. In my case, I needed the arrays...